# Deleting from state in React Native still displays icon

Tags: react-native

I am storing an array of images in state. After each image is added I display an X icon in the corner of it, so that the user can delete the image if they'd like. This works, however the X icon is still displayed when the image is removed. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
deleteTempImage(index) {
  let images = this.state.images
  images.splice(index, 1)
  this.setState({images: images})
}

render() {
  return (
    {this.state.images.map((image, index) => (
      <View key={'view_' + index}>
        <Icon key={'icon' + index} onPress={() => this.deleteTempImage(index)} name='ios-close-circle' style={styles.closeIcon} /> 
        <Image key={'image' + index} source={{uri: image}} style={styles.image} /> 
      </View>
    ))}
  )
}
```

Comment: Your code is both correct (in my opinion) and works on my system as intended. You do have the `map()` in your render function, right?

Comment: Yes, I do. I ended up solving this by wrapping the Icon in a TouchableOpacity element and moving the onPress action here. I still think my code above should work, interested if someone will have a reason for the weird behavior.